# Extract information from each iteration of GridSearchCV to compute confusion matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search, gridsearchcv

I am working on a machine learning project using sklearn GridSearchCV. My goal is that from the output of the GridSearchCV I need to find all the parameter settings which give the positive predicted value of greater than 0.95 and compute the confusion matrix for each of them. I have implemented the customized score function for the grid to compute the PPV value and inside the score function, I am computing the confusion matrix and writing them into a text file. However, due to the parallel execution, I can't keep track of them.

Is there a way that I can accomplish this?

Comment: `cv_results_` stores all the information. see `https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html`

Comment: Hi Osman, cv_results_ gives the overall score but I want to compute the confusion matrix for each iteration so I would need to know the true positive, false positive and etc. Is there a way that I could get the exact prediction results (y_pred) for each iteration?

Comment: Hmm, for that you need to use a list/dict of scoring that will store true +ve, true -ve etc. See `https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_multi_metric_evaluation.html`

Comment: @OsmanMamun Thank you very much for your advice. I implemented multiple evaluation metrics and it works as I expected!

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the answer:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
all_conf_mats = []
for i in range(len(grid_search.cv_results_['params'])):
    clf = grid_search.cv_results_['estimator'][i] 
    pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test, pred)
    all_conf_mats.append(conf_mat)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most correct and easiest way is to declare a scoring function, that wraps it as a dict

```
def confusionMatrix_scoring(y, y_pred):
    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y, y_pred, labels=[0, 1]).ravel()
    return {'tp':float(tp), 'fp':float(fp), 'fn':float(fn), 'tn':float(tn), 
            'acc':float((tp+tn)/(tp+tn+fn+fp))}

confMatrix_scorer = sklearn.metrics.make_scorer(confusionMatrix_scoring,
                                                greater_is_better=True)

grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid=param_grid,
                    scoring=confMatrix_scorer, refit=False)

grid.fit(X, y)
```

You will be able to access the elements for each fold and also the averages for each hyperparameter-set (HP-set):

```
grid.cv_results_['split0_test_tp'] # TP scores for each HP-set
grid.cv_results_['mean_test_tp']   # average TP score for each HP-set
```

You can use these scores to reconstruct a HP-set's confusion matrix, or a particular fold's confusion matrix within a HP-set.
Eg. getting the confusion matrix of the 0.th (1.st) fold/split of the 11th (12th) HP-set

```
pd.DataFrame([
    [grid.cv_results_['split0_test_tp'][11], grid.cv_results_['split0_test_fn'][11]],
    [grid.cv_results_['split0_test_fp'][11], grid.cv_results_['split0_test_tn'][11]]
], columns=['P', 'N'], index=['P', 'N'])
```

You can also easily reconstruct a HP-set's averaged confusion matrix

Eg. getting the averaged confusion matrix of the 9.th (10.th) HP-set:

```
pd.DataFrame([
    [grid.cv_results_['mean_test_tp'][9], grid.cv_results_['mean_test_fn'][9]],
    [grid.cv_results_['mean_test_fp'][9], grid.cv_results_['mean_test_tn'][9]]
], columns=['P', 'N'], index=['P', 'N'])
```